# How to hide field from Json response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to hide from public api simple Serializer field (created without any model). How I can solve this?

```
same_result = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can use [write_only](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#write_only) argument to achieve this goal :**

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    same_result = serializers.SerializerMethodField(write_only=True)
```

Comment: its not working with SerializerMethodField.  Will be AssertionError: May not set both `read_only` and `write_only`

SerializerMethodField. This is a read-only field. It gets its value by calling a method on the serializer class it is attached to. It can be used to add any sort of data to the serialized representation of your object. Signature: SerializerMethodField(method_name=None)

Comment: Are you using a model as Meta or not ? Because it's seems that you added read_only=True to the same field. Or can you show all your serializer ?

Answer (score 0):

you can override the to  to_representation method

```py
     def to_representation(self, instance):
      data = super().to_representation(instance)     

      data.pop('same_result')
      return data
```

Comment: This function remove same_result. I'm need to stay for private api, and remove for public

Comment: you can make two serializers on inherited from other  and hide it in one of two or working  view level iself

Comment: this is not a good solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you could either use the [permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isadminuser) configuration to identify either a public or private user based on membership of a group, then you could switch in the View, something like:

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        if request.user.groups.filter(name="private").exists():    
            serializer = PrivateUserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        else:
            serializer = PublicUserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Then you define the fields on your serializer as you wish.